# What game is featured in Amazon new phone page?

Tags: game-identification

Saw this game on Amazon's promotion page for their new phone - anyone know what game this is?

[image]

Comment: I've become so accustomed to closing as soon as I see game id tag I was genuinely shocked to see a screenshot load. +1 ;)

Comment: I know its not puzzle quest 2, but the gameplay looks similar.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you look closely on the amazon page, you can see the game this screenshot is from. It's "Saber's Edge".

[image]

It seems that this game is not yet released (pretty much nothing can be found online). It's likely that it will be released with the amazon fire phone.

Comment: good eye! (12 chars)